# Multiple pages for custom_post_type posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a `custom_post_type` that creates the posts for `campaign_posts`, they are displayed singularly on the front-end of my site with the page template `single-campaign_posts.php`.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is;

- `single-campaign_posts.php` displays the post (already taken care of)
- A second page that will display a frontend editor of the post (contents of this page is already taken care of
- A third page that will display analytics for the post (again, the contents of this page has been taken care if)

So when a post is viewed they can click a link within `single-campaign_posts.php` to display either the analytics page or edit page. The pages that are linked to must be;

- able to recognize that the contents of that page relate to the post
- the URL slug is for example if the post was `/campaigns/dummy-post` would be `/campaigns/dummy-post/analytics` for the analytics page and `/campaigns/dummy-post/edit-campaign` for the edit page.

I have tried using `nav tabs` to do this and it works, however, I would rather have the contents on separate pages.

I hope this enough information to obtain my goals in this. I cannot see much point in adding details of the `functions.php`or `single-campaign_posts.php` but if they are required then please let me know.

I hate seeing posts like this, but I have come up empty on searches for a solution. In its very basic form, I need three pages that all relate to the single post.

[image: Example of <code>single-campaign_posts.php</code>]

Thank you for your time and if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this now.

The solution was to use `Rewrite API/add rewrite endpoint` as seen [Rewrite API/add rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

An example is posted in this question - [Create Post tabs in single-{content-type}.php with Custom Field values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104955/create-post-tabs-in-single-content-type-php-with-custom-field-values)